# handling transactions with EF5 using repository patren?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In was using EF with with `Repository` and `Unit of Work` patterns. My reason for using `Unit of Work` is to have transaction like mechanism where I need to work with multiple entities.

I read EF internally implement Unit of Work pattern so it can handle transactions. I m working with EF5 using generic repository pattern. Can you please guide me how I can use existing transaction support with EF5 using generic repository ?

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call SaveChanges() on your DbContext you have an implicit transaction so either all your changes will succeed or all of them will fail.

Comment: thanks, does it mean if work with different repositories (Repository<Student>, Repository<Teacher>, Repository<School>) and in any of them if I call SaveChanges(), it will save changes of all DbSets(Student, Treacher, School)
and it will work for all CRUD operations ?

Comment: If they all work on the same underlying ObjectContext/DbContext, then yes, so it depends on your strategy for when a new context should be created. But basically the idea behind the UoW pattern is that you can have changes in multiple repositories in one single unit of work, and commit them all at once.